# TensorFlow - How to train ANN with Plain TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm a fresh man in TensorFlow and recently I need to use it to train an ANN without the usage of TensorFlow's high level API.

But, something went wrong with the following code:

## 1. Define relevant parameters for ANN

```
n_inputs = getVectorLength(instance2Path)
n_outputs = 1
n_hidden1 = 66
n_hidden2 = 24
learning_rate = 0.01
n_epochs = 400
batch_size = 50
```

## 2. Create every layers in ANN

```
def neuron_layer(X, n_neurons, name, activation=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        n_inputs = int(X.get_shape()[1])
        stddevValue = 2 / np.sqrt(n_inputs)
        initWeight = tf.truncated_normal((n_inputs, n_neurons), stddev=stddevValue)
         W = tf.Variable(initWeight, name='weights', dtype='float')
         b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_neurons]), name='biases')
         z = tf.matmul(X, W) + b
         if activation == 'relu':
             return tf.nn.relu(z)
         elif name == 'outputs':
             return tf.sigmoid(z)
         pass
     pass
```

## 3. Build TensorFlow graph

```
 X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name='X')
 y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None), name='y')
 hidden1 = neuron_layer(X, n_hidden1, 'hidden1', activation='relu')
 hidden2 = neuron_layer(hidden1, n_hidden2, 'hidden2', activation='relu')
 outputs = neuron_layer(hidden2, n_outputs, 'outputs')
 init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

## 4. Run with Session

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  print n_inputs
  sess.run(init)

  samples, labels = prepareSampleAndLabelAndFeature(ConfigVars.FeatureSelectionStrategy2, instance2Path)
  sample = np.array(samples[0])
  sample = sample.reshape(1, 170)
  sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: sample})
  print outputs.eval()
```

## 5. Problems

After running the code above, I got following exceptions:

```
Caused by op u'X', defined at:
  File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/TesTensorFlow/TrainANN/ANNTest.py", line 45, in <module>
    X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs), name='X')
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/TensorFlow_GPU/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/TensorFlow_GPU/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1997, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/TensorFlow_GPU/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/TensorFlow_GPU/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda/envs/TensorFlow_GPU/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'X' with dtype float
     [[Node: X = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

In my view, maybe the problem counts on the data type of X, but I have checked! The input vector of X is like [0,1,0,1.....] only consisting of 0-1 values, and the label is 0 and 1, or a typical binary classification problem.

Comment: what's the shape and type of `samples`

Comment: samples and labels are all python built-in 'list' type, samples in shape of (39,170) and labels is (39,), a 1D list

Comment: try `sample = sample.reshape(1, 170).astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which may be the source of the error:

1. [When reshaping a np.ndarray, the shape is considered as one variable.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) e.g. `sample = sample.reshape([1, 170])` where `[1, 170]` is the desired shape.
2. Since `X` is defined as a placeholder of size `[none, n_inputs]`, the shape of `sample` must match that shape. e.g. `n_inputs` is 170.